# How to build curl with boringssl?

Tags: curl, boringssl

I'm trying to build curl with boringssl on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have boringssl built OK.

With curl 7.53 I configure using:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/home/john/dev/boringssl
```

and the output says "  SSL support:      enabled (BoringSSL)" OK.

But when I `make`, I get errors starting with

```
  CC       vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo
In file included from vtls/openssl.c:86:0:
/usr/include/openssl/ui.h:85:1: error: unknown type name ‘UI’
 UI *UI_new(void);
 ^
/usr/include/openssl/ui.h:86:1: error: unknown type name ‘UI’
 UI *UI_new_method(const UI_METHOD *method);
 ^
/usr/include/openssl/ui.h:86:25: error: unknown type name ‘UI_METHOD’
 UI *UI_new_method(const UI_METHOD *method);
                         ^
```

and ending with

```
Makefile:2023: recipe for target 'vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/dev/curl-7.53.0/lib'
Makefile:734: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/john/dev/curl-7.53.0/lib'
Makefile:893: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm not sure if this `/usr/include/openssl/ui.h` header should be used when curl is configured to build with boringssl, it seems this file only exists in OpenSSL, not boringssl.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no `openssl/ui.h` in the boringssl tree, your build clearly found another set of include files (plain OpenSSL I'd guess).

This is how I build with boringssl:

### build boringssl

$HOME/src is where I put the code in this example. You can pick wherever you like.

```
$ cd $HOME/src
$ git clone https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl
$ cd boringssl
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=on ..
$ make
```

### set up the build tree to get detected by curl's configure

In the boringssl source tree root, make sure there's a `lib` and an `include` dir. The `lib` dir should contain the two libs (I make them symlinks into the build dir). The `include` dir is already present by default. Make and populate `lib`  like this (commands issued in the source tree root, not in the `build/` subdirectory).

```
$ mkdir lib
$ cd lib
$ ln -s ../build/ssl/libssl.a
$ ln -s ../build/crypto/libcrypto.a
```

### configure curl

`LIBS=-lpthread ./configure --with-ssl=$HOME/src/boringssl` (where I point out the root of the boringssl tree)

verify that at the end of the configure run, it should say it detected BoringSSL to be used

### build curl

run `make` in the curl source tree

Now you can install curl normally with `make install` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

There was no `lib` dir after building boringssl, so I made `lib` a symlink to `build` (although this only contains one lib, libgtest.a). 

Which are the two libs which I should put in the `lib` dir?

The configure run ending with:
    checking for ssl with RSAglue/rsaref libs in use... checking for SSL_connect in -lssl... (cached) no
    no
    configure: error: OpenSSL libs and/or directories were not found where specified!

Comment: Worked great, thanks a lot! This works perfect. (maybe that `cmake ..` should be `cmake .`, I had to `cd` in to `build` to run `cmake ..`)

Comment: Thank you for these instructions @Daniel Stenberg, I was able to compile `curl` with BoringSSL with the help.  I had to make an alteration to the `cmake` portion to be `cmake -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=on ..` instead.  I'm not an expert at linux / compiling apps, so I didn't want to update your answer in case it's bad advice.

Comment: Tried to compile the latest cURL with BoringSSL and nghttp2 by this instruction. Can't `make` cURL because of this error: `/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/boringssl/lib/libcrypto.a(bcm.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`. Any ideas how to deal with it? @Matthew isn't it the reason why you added `DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=on`?  @Daniel-Stenberg ?

Comment: Solution has been found on github: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/8416 . I've updated the answer accordingly.